# How to sketch the discrete time graph?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions, biology

In order to sketch following question what I have done so far: $ lim_{Nt->0} F(N_{t})= 0 $ and $ lim_{Nt->\infty} F(N_{t})=r$ (For the case of s=0). Now since this a discrete time graph I am not sure if the derivative features can be used? My intuition is that you can't since the stationary points can't be find in that way but rather they are found by setting F(Nt)=0. Therefore, my question is what are the steps to go about sketching discrete time graphs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a *qualitative* behavior of $f$, to have an idea on how the population will behave in the next time step, so you can omit the details about the discrete nature of $t$, $N_t$ in itself is a continuous variable

[image]

In the limit $N_t \to 0$, $f(N_t)$ also goes to zero, *independent* of $s$ (apply L'Hopital's rule), and for large populations $f(N_t)\to r$

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand the limit analysis but there are many functions that we could with those limit properties that may have a different shape when graphed. I am unsure on how to get that shape.

Comment: Qualitatively speaking, you have a function that starts at $0$, and asymptotically goes to $1$, slower with larger values of $s$. Unless the function is extremely pathological (which is not your case) there not many options: raise smoothly from $0$, go smoothly to $1$

Comment: I thought it went to r asymptotically rather than 1 speaking by the limit

Comment: @chloeloughan You're right, goes to $r$, it is just that I divide by $r$ (see the figure above)

Comment: 'Slower with larger values' what impact would this have on the shape? Also, by any chance would you have any recommended literature on sketching functions?

Comment: @chloeloughan Slower in the sense that it takes longer to climb up, since you have it in the denominator. Any introductory book to calculus probably deals with these problems